# Firefox security message for no particular reason

Tags: html, security, firefox

Firefox 52 introduced warnings for login forms on insecure pages. It displays a struck-through lock icon and the warning:

> This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be comprised.

I get this warning on the page http://www.kik.de. The problem here is that the page does *not* contain any login form. A secure connection is not really needed here.

On some subpages the warning disappears (http://www.kik.de/agb) so I figured the problem must be somewhere in the content, as header and footer are always the same. I tried reducing the content on the start page and at some point the warning disappeared there as well. But the content removed were just teasers, nothing special.

The only pattern I see is: more content shows the warning, less content fixes this. Is there anything I don't see?

Comment: Which part? No warning at all or warning on all pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook tracking snippet is causing this.

In case the page displays products, the fb tracking sends them with a post request home.

The request looks like this:

```
 Request URL: https://www.facebook.com/tr/
 Request Method: POST
 Request Body: contains all the products on the page in schema.org format
```

So the answer is: When the page contains products, Facebook tracking makes a post request, causing Firefox to think that the user wants to log in to Facebook.